# Can not type in tilde and open curly brace in linux terminal

Tags: linux, vmware-player

I cannot type a tilde `~` or an open curly brace `{` within Linux. But a closing curly brace `}` does work.

I assume some special key handling is activated despite Ubuntu's Universal Access being disabled, e.g. if I type `{` and scroll afterwards, Firefox zooms the current page.

I am using Windows 7 with German keyboard and German keyboard setting. UI language is English. On top I use a VMWare Player 6.0.4 to run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: it's impossible you can't type ~ in terminal because it refers to home, I think the problem is with vmware or maybe the difference between keyboard language and UI language

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* hosted by *Windows 7* / *VMWare Player 6.0.5*, except { [ ] } ~ etc. don't work ANYWHERE. The key is recognized, though.